# Are there any sutta references to the way S.N. Goenkaji teaches Vipassana?

Tags: vipassana, sn-goenka

I have done 4 10-day vipassana retreats as taught by Goenkaji some 4-5 years back. As of now, from readings online and reading questions and answers on this BSE website I come to understand that vipassana does not mean 'body scanning' for sensations to eradicate samkharas but the word 'vipassana' means 'insight'.

But as Goenkaji teaches it in the retreats he means (if I interpreat him correctly) by vipassana as the 'body scan' technique that he teaches.

Are there any suttas which explain this technique or which tell that by body scan, insight or vipassana will arise?
Is the technique also taught by Buddha somewhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no suttas that describe the specific technique of Goenka.

However, a natural 'scanning' of the body (including awareness and dissolution of sankharas) will occur when [Anapanasati](https://www.dhammatalks.net/Books3/Bhikkhu_Buddhadasa_Anapanasati_Mindfulness_with_Breathing.htm#APPENDIX%20E) or [Kayagatasati](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/mn/mn.119.than.html) are developed.